# How to animate width of a holder in a CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to animate a bar (just an ImageView) in the onBindViewHolder method.

If i don't try to animate it, it is working perfectly with this line:

```
holder.progressBar.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

But as soon as i add a function to animate this bar/imageView, it doesn't work.
I can see the bar only on the first item in the recyclerView and the bar is not animated.

this is the code that i use. what is the problem?

Thanks to all.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        //holder.progressBarWeatherFactor.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
        animateWidth(0, 100, holder.progressBar.getLayoutParams());
    }

    public void animateWidth(int start, int end, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams myBar)
    {
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(1800);

        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate( ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
            {
                myBar.width = ((int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to help, i found a solution, maybe not the best but it is working and i hope it will help!
(the /10*3/64 is in relation with my image size, so don't matter of this)

```
@Override    
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    animateWidth(0, 100, holder.progressBar);
}

public void animateWidth(int initialValue, int finalValue, ImageView image)
{
    image.setPivotX(0f);

    PropertyValuesHolder barWidth;
    barWidth = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0, ((float)(((image.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)/10)*3)/64)*finalValue);

    ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(image, barWidth).setDuration(800).start();
}
```